# Different general form equations for the same plane

Tags: vectors, cross-product

The general form equation of a plane in $R^3$ is:

$$ax + by + cz = d$$

I am given 3 points and asked to derive a general form equation for a plane passing through those three points, say, A, B and C.

The approach I take is to:

- Choose one of those three points, say, A
- Find the vector from A to B: $\vec {v_1} = \vec b - \vec a$
- Find the vector from A to C: $\vec {v_2} = \vec c - \vec a$
- Find the normal vector, n, to the plane by finding the cross product of said vectors $$\vec n = \vec v_1 \times \vec v_2$$
- Use the normal form equation for a plane in $R^3$, i.e. $\vec n \bullet \vec x = \vec n \bullet \vec p$, to substitute in the normal vector, n, calculated above and the point from which it was calculated, in this case, A.

If the answer that I get is correct then I should expect substituting any point A B or C into the equation $$ax + by + cz = d$$
... to hold. However it doesn't. The equation only holds for one point, A, and not B and C.

What am I doing incorrectly to derive the equation of a plane passing through point A, B and C?

Comment: Method is fine, your algebra must be wrong.

Comment: You have described the process just fine.  And if you are indeed following it, you should have the correct answers.  So, if not, there must be a mistake in your arithmetic.

Comment: I think you need to come up with a concrete example of three points and show us your work. The entries of the normal vector of the plane are indeed the values $a,b,c$

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. It was indeed the algebra. I spent the last hour looking at where I went wrong in my methodology. I used A = (-4, -1, -1), B = (-2, 0, 1) and C = (-1, -2, -3). AB = [2 1 2] and AC = [3 -1 -2]. When I took the cross product, I somehow botched the signs. The insane confusion was compounded by summation errors in the end which left me questioning my methodology. My final answer is 2y - z = -1 and it matches for all points. I might have even substituted in x values despite there being none in the general equation. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: When you find a cross product, always check to see that it really is perpendicular to both original vectors, using dot product  and care.